# Googlebot + IFrames?

Tags: iframe, seo

How does googlebot treat iframes? Does it follow the src attribute like a link? Is the iframe content analyzed as if it was part of the page where it is included?

Comment: @casperOne: how about moving this to webmasters stackexchange instead of just closing it?

Comment: Would be closed on webmasters as a cross-site duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/do-we-still-need-to-avoid-using-frame-iframe-for-good-seo

Comment: @casperOne : ok, then let's delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> IFrames are sometimes used to display content on web pages. **Content displayed via iFrames may not be indexed** and available to appear in Google's search results. We recommend that you avoid the use of iFrames to display content. If you do include iFrames, make sure to **provide additional text-based links to the content they display, so that Googlebot can crawl and index this content.**

From the [Google Webmaster Guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=72746&query=iframe&topic=&type=)

The iframe content isn't included in the original page. If you want the content indexed, try providing a text link to the src page. If you don't want it indexed, use the meta robots tag or robots.txt to restrict the file.

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotal evidence suggests it treats it like a link (so you can end up with a page designed to be viewed inside the frame being loaded on its own via a link from a search engine).